# How to get native country name with Google Closure I18n?

Tags: localization, internationalization, google-closure-library

I am trying to see if I can use Google Closure library form my webapp's internationalization and localization needs. I tried to find any tutorials on the subject, but could not find any and it seems I am stuck when trying on my own.

I am interested in getting the native name of a country.

I am not sure how I should use the the goog.locale component, though. It seems that for example, `goog.locale.getNativeCountryName('EE')` always returns 'EE', instead of 'Eesti' as I would expect it to.

```
goog.require('goog.locale');
...
console.log( goog.locale.getNativeCountryName('EE') ) // Outputs: 'EE'
```

Maybe I am missing some dependencies?

EDIT: After fiddling around a little bit I discovered that if I use et_EE instead of EE, I get the expected 'Eesti'. However, that just seems plain wrong. et_EE is a locale code, not a country code, and the function clearly expects a country code... Maybe I am still doing something wrong?

Comment: are you using the templating language as well?

Comment: For each locale you compile a version of the templates down to javascript and then compile a version for that language. at least this is how we are doing it.

Comment: I am not using the templating language. The question is where do I get the data for Localized language and country names?

Comment: @ragulka, what do you expect the function to return?

Comment: @Shervin - like stated in the question, I am expecting that the function returns "Eesti", which is "Estonia" in estonian (the native country name for EE).

Comment: @ragulka See my updated answer below. According to API docs, your assumption that _"the function clearly expects a country code"_ is not correct. The function receives a language code and returns the country name for that language in that language; `et -> (which is language of) -> Estonia -> (which in Estonian is) -> Eesti`

Comment: @Shervin Thanks. I have accepted your answer and changed my question title & wording to better reflect my original issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getNativeCountryName()` receives a language code (in this case `et`) and not a country code (`EE`). See the [API docs](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn-history/r27/trunk/closure/goog/docs/closure_goog_locale_locale.js.html):

> Returns the country name of the provided **language code** in its native
>   language.

Therefore:

```
goog.require('goog.locale');
...
console.log( goog.locale.getNativeCountryName('et') ) // Should return 'Eesti'
```

Comment: Yeah, I should have read the docs more carefully. But given like that, the function is useless for me, because I was trying to get the native name for a specific country, not a language's country.

Comment: To elaborate - the docs are misleading: they say that getNativeCountryName accepts 1 argument `countryCode` - "Code to lookup the country name for.", while the function description reads "Returns the country name of the provided language code in its native language."

Comment: @ragulka, yeah. It's a documentation bug apparently. For getting the native name for a specific country, why don't you use `getLocalizedCountryName`?